# Sort order to order this list in a specific order

Tags: sort, locale, r

I know there are tons of sorting questions on here, but I'm unable to resolve my use case.

I am trying to sort a list in R (on Ubuntu 16.04) and am at my wits end! I've been trying to mess with the `LC_ALL=C` and `collate` settings and can get results to sort differently, but I'm unable to get the result I need. This is what I need:

`2014_Actual / 2014_Target / 2014_Percent / 2015_Actual / 2015_Target / 2015_Percent`

The trick I use in windows is to delete the underscore, so:
`2014_Actual / 2014_Target / 2014Percent / 2015_Actual / 2015_Target / 2015Percent`, which is acceptable to my users. But obviously this doesn't work in Linux since it ignores the underscore.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I could get the above mentioned sort order at the `LC_ALL` level?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Adding clarity: the problem is that when I sort the above in Linux, it ignores the underscore and gives:
`2014_Actual / 2014Percent / 2014_Target /  2015_Actual / 2015Percent / 2015_Target`

Comment: this is *within* R, you're saying?

Comment: is: `mv 2014_Target 2014_target; mv 2015_Target 2015_target` acceptable?

Comment: If this is a question about how to write it in R, that's more suited to SO than to U&L, is it not?

Comment: Correct @JeffSchaller, it's within R... but the Linux sort environment comes through.

Comment: Also correct @Theophrastus, that's exactly it.

Comment: DopeGhoti, it's not an R sort issue... supplementing my answer.

Comment: what are you doing in `R` to call out to the Linux environment?  (and is renaming Target to target acceptable?)

Comment: I'm not an R person. Are these fields on a single line, or does the `/` character represent a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand the entirety of your question,
but if I were doing that in Unix, I would do

```
sed -e 's/Actual/1Actual/' -e 's/Target/2Target/' -e 's/Percent/3Percent/' |
    sort |
    sed -e 's/1Actual/Actual/' -e 's/2Target/Target/' -e 's/3Percent/Percent/'
```

Comment: GENIUS!!!!! RENAME SORT RENAME......... DUuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuh omg I want to die